# Simple exmple of email password login with anuglarfire2

Tags: angular, angularfire2

My objective is to build a simple Angular app with angularfire2 and email password authentication.

I have read the description [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md), and understand that I should read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) for more methods. But the thing is that I don't quit understand the example app - to me it looks like it makes a reference to a non-existing "this. afAuth"?

Can you help with a simple example - or lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Please try first this will be more benificial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a "non-existent `this.afAuth`". It refers to the `AngularFireAuth` injected in the constructor. What you need is the [`signInWithEmailAndPassword` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth):

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  login(email: string, password: string): void {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => console.log('logged in'))
      .catch((err: Error) => console.error(err.message));
  }
}
```

Then, just pass the credentials (email, password) in your form and call the `login` method.